# svn - single file not under version control

Tags: linux, file, svn

I've added a new file (pdf) to a directory and when I try and commit the new file it is saying that it is not under version control, the directory and every other file in the directory is under version control as when I tried `svn add *` it listed all the files as being under version control.

What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

EDIT: OK I am now able to add the file, am I right in saying that the `svn add *` command added this file under version control thus allowing me to commit the file?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `svn status FILE`?

Comment: See my edit, it seemed to work but would like to know why.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the `svn add *` did that.

You have to `svn add Name_of_File` any new files before you can svn commit them.

Answer (score 5):

you can try something like this...

in the checkout directory run this command

```
svn add . --force
```

then just commit it all

```
svn commit -m "your text" *
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the `add` command doesn't do it, and still gives an error. the best thing is to perform the `svn cleanup [PATH...]` command then try to add or commit.